# Ordering div list with decimal values group by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

After testing many solutions founded, none of them is sorting correctly. I need to sort a list grouped by a classification field:

```
<div id="idx-list-ctn" class="list-ctn">
    <div class="header-ctn">
        <div>Fornecedores</div>
        <div><img id="lst-order-by-btn" src="/Images/distance-19x19.png">Ordenar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19324" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="2" data-distance="2">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19325" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="1" data-distance="2">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19326" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="1" data-distance="2,2">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19327" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="2" data-distance="1,9">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19328" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="1" data-distance="0,9">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst-19329" class="partner-ctn" data-classification="2" data-distance="1,7">
        <div class="info-wrp lp-blc-rate-2">
            <div class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the function I have build until now:

```
$("#idx-list-ctn").find('.partner-ctn').sort(function (a, b) {

  var aa = $(a).data('classification');
  var bb = $(b).data('classification');
  if (aa === bb) {
    aa = $(a).data('distance').toString().replace(',', '.');
    bb = $(b).data('distance').toString().replace(',', '.');
    aa = parseFloat(aa);
    bb = parseFloat(bb);
  }
  return aa - bb;
}).appendTo("#idx-list-ctn");
```

The expected result is:
Ascending: classification: 1 | Distance: 0,9 -> 2 -> 2,2 » classification: 2 | Distance: 1,7 -> 1,9 -> 2

Descending: classification: 1 | Distance: 2,2 -> 2 -> 0,9 » classification: 2 | Distance: 2 -> 1,9 -> 1,7

But I get:
Ascending: OK

Descending: classification: 2 | Distance: 2 -> 1,9 -> 1,7 » classification: 1 | Distance: 2,2 -> 2 -> 0,9

Classification group 2 is coming to the top of the list, but should remain after the classification 1 group.

Comment: @Yogi works like a charm! Thank you! Now I just have to get ordered grouped by classification.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if I understand the problem correctly.

```
$("#idx-list-ctn")
  .find('.partner-ctn')
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = $(a).data('classification');
    var bb = $(b).data('classification');
    if (aa === bb) {
      aa = $(a).data('distance');
      bb = $(b).data('distance');
      aa = parseFloat(aa.replace(',', '.'));
      bb = parseFloat(bb.replace(',', '.'));
    }
    return aa - bb;
  })
  .appendTo("#idx-list-ctn");
```

Comment: Almost perfect! Thanks! I have used Yogi tip or else I get a replace script error. The only issue now is that the lower classification goes to the top, but I want to keep them in the same group's position, and inside the group, ordered by distance. Any idea how can I achieve that? I have completed the question with the expected order. Thanks

Comment: @Yogi I have updated my question with your solution, Thanks. BTW any idea how I can solve the classification ordering?

Comment: bb = parseFloat(aa);
aa = parseFloat(bb);

To sort in descending order, you need to change this part of the code.